# "Send Email to The Owner" on Lead Conversion Page

Tags: lead-conversion

some set of users should not be allowed to use the check box "Send Email to the Owner" On Lead conversion Page.

Is there any possible way to restrict this option?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Recordtype then remove this fields from recordtype
 **OR** 
GO to FLS and uncheck the visible checkbox infront of your field name
 **OR** 
Go to Permission set and remove the access

Comment: Hi @CloudZigZag i couldn't see this field "Send Email to the Owner" under Lead object. but It is available on lead conversion page.